# My made PHP Blocker not working

Tags: php, php-7, php-5.3

This code is working:

https://www.skools.cu.ma/contents/posts/Comma.php:

```
<?php
    require ('./../../blocks/block_function.php');
?>
```

https://www.skools.cu.ma/blocks/block_function.php:

```
<?php
    $badcomment_comma_post = array("137.97.11.13", "222.222.222", "333.333.333");
    if ( in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $badcomment_comma_post) ) { 
       die("<script>window.location = 'https://www.skools.cu.ma/blocks/bad_comment.php';</script>You have been blocked");
    }
?>
```

But when I tried separating the ip addresses and redirector code, it didn't work and I got no PHP error messages:

https://www.skools.cu.ma/blocks/block_function.php:

```
<?php 
    $file = file_get_contents('./../../blocks/bad_commented_ip.txt'); 
    $badcomment_comma_post = array($file);
    if ( in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $badcomment_comma_post) ) {
        die("<script>window.location = 'https://www.skools.cu.ma/blocks/bad_comment.php';</script>You have been blocked");
    }
?>
```

https://www.skools.cu.ma/blocks/bad_commented_ip.txt:

```
"137.97.11.13", "222.222.222", "333.333.333"
```

Please help?

Comment: This bit doesn't work: `array($file);` ... explode the contents instead.

Comment: Then how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are running into is this bit:

```
$file = file_get_contents('./../../blocks/bad_commented_ip.txt'); 
$badcomment_comma_post = array($file);
```

What that actually is doing (if you `print_r($badcomment_comma_post);`) is making **one** array element with a value of the *entire file*. Not multiple array elements of each IP:

```
Array
(
    [0] => "137.97.11.13", "222.222.222", "333.333.333"
)
```

If your file is actually in the format of `"137.97.11.13", "222.222.222", "333.333.333"`, then consider the following examples to do:

```
// Example 1, explode!
$file = file_get_contents('./../../blocks/bad_commented_ip.txt');
$cleaned = str_replace(array('"',' '),'',$file);
$badcomment_comma_post = explode(',',$cleaned);
```

What that is doing is reading in the file, stripping out all the quotes and spaces, and then exploding on comma to make the array you want.

Another way to do it, is with json in the file (but your file contents are not exactly right):

```
// Example 2, json!
$file = file_get_contents('./../../blocks/bad_commented_ip.txt');
$json = '['. $file .']';
$badcomment_comma_post = json_decode($json);
```

So what that does, is take the file contents, wraps them in brackets so that it is better json format, and then finally decoding that json array to a php array.

The above two examples will output `print_r($badcomment_comma_post);`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 137.97.11.13
    [1] => 222.222.222
    [2] => 333.333.333
)
```